# DNS name for virtual machine after Classic to ARM migration

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I was asked, from Microsoft Azure, to migrate my server (only one), in Classic resource group, to ARM.  My server has only a web service, published by IIS and it's used by this url:

https://vm-avl-ws5635.cloudapp.net/xxx/yyy/zzz.asmx

I'm worried about the domain name: vm-avl-ws5635.cloudapp.net, it is the DNS configured for my server, in order to set available for external users to my web service.

After the migration, is the domain name changed?, or, will I be able to continue accessing my ws using the URL before wrote?

I have also the remote desktop port available to admin my server in remote way.  After the migration, is it require to reconfigure that, or, is it not required?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: by the way, I tried the prepare wizard, all can be migrated (network, vm, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

After migration, the internal domain name of Azure VM changed to `something.internal.cloudapp.net`. If you want to access it from external users, you can [configure the FQDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn) of Azure VM like `DNSnamelable.region.cloudapp.azure.com`.

If you want to use your custom domain `www.contoso.com` to access your Azure VM, you could add `A` or `CNAME` records to map your public IP address or FQDN of this VM in your DNS provider.

After migration, if there is network security group in your existing virtual network or subnet that you VM exists, you need to add an inbound port rule for the remote desktop port 3389. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-network-security-group#create-a-network-security-group) for more details. You can check the NSG from your Virtual machine--->Networking--->Inbound port rules in the Azure portal.